# Update an array item of Mongodb with $and query

Tags: mongodb, mongotemplate

Hi I am trying to increment the count of the matching requirement in an array. My sample collection looks like the following:

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("60760ba2e870fa518f2ae48b"),
  "userId": "6075f7289822d94dca8066b4",
  "requirements": [
    {
      "searchText": "zee5",
      "planType": "basic",
      "mode": "PRIVATE",
      "count": 32.0
    },
    {
      "searchText": "sony",
      "planType": "standard",
      "mode": "PUBLIC",
      "count": 12.0
    },
    {
      "searchText": "prime",
      "planType": "premium",
      "mode": "PRIVATE",
      "count": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

If a user searches for prime, with filter premium and PRIVATE, then the count of the last requirement should be updated. If he searches for prime, with filter standard and PRIVATE, then the new requirement will be inserted with count 1.

I am doing in two steps. First I fire an update with the following query and then if no update, I fire a push query with count 1:

```
db.getCollection('userProfile').update({ "$and" : [{ "requirements.searchText" : {$eq:"prime"}}, {"requirements.mode" : {$eq: "PUBLIC"}}, {"requirements.planType": {$eq: "standard"}},  { "userId" : "6075f7289822d94dca8066b4"}]}, {$inc: {"requirements.$.count" : 1}})
```

I was expecting that the above query will not update any requirement, since there is no exact match. Interestingly, it increments the count of the second requirement with (sony, standard, public). What is wrong with the query? How can I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Demo - with Update - https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ISXaAayxxv

Demo No update - https://mongoplayground.net/p/88bTj3lz7U_

Use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to make sure all properties are present in the same object inside the array

> The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

```
db.collection.update(
{
  "requirements": {
    $elemMatch: { "searchText": "prime","mode": "PUBLIC", "planType": "standard" }
  },
  "userId": "6075f7289822d94dca8066b4"
},
{ $inc: { "requirements.$.count": 1 } }
)
```

---

**Problem -**

Your current query will match any document with all these fields in
`requirements` array in any object, if they match 1 property in 1 index of the array and another match in the next index query will find the document valid.

```
  "searchText": "prime",
  "mode": "PUBLIC",
  "planType": "standard"
```